# Not getting the exact colored area(MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, plot, fill

Good afternoon,
I have the following code and its result with me.
as you can see the colored region that i got was three parts. The real colored part i want is the middle one. Can anyone help me out with it please? 
Here is the code

```
gamma=20;
P=0.5;
N=P.*gamma;
lamdazero=1550;
lamdasignal=linspace(1540,1580,100000);
lamdapump=1560;
beta3=0.06;
beta4=-1*10^-4;
c=2*pi*3*10^5;
L=1;
A0=(1./lamdapump) -(1./lamdazero);
B0=(1./lamdapump) -(1./lamdasignal);
Third0=beta3.*(c.^3).*A0.*(B0.^2);
Fourth0=beta4.*(1./2).*c.^4.*(A0.^2).*(B0.^2);
Fourorder=c.^4.*beta4.*(1/12).*(B0).^4;
deltabeta=Third0+Fourth0+Fourorder;
lamdasignal22=linspace(1550,1560,100000);
g0=1.1*10^-11;
Aeff=11*10^-12;
PSBS=0.08;
SBS=(g0.*PSBS.*1000)./Aeff ;
     f0 = ones(size(lamdasignal));
    f0 = 0 .* f0;

    f1 = ones(size([lamdasignal]));
    f1 = -2.*N .* f1;

    f2 = ones(size(lamdasignal22));
    f2 = -4.*N .* f2;

         PA=deltabeta./N;
```

[image]
    figure
    hax=axes;

```
[ax,p1,p2] = plotyy(lamdasignal,deltabeta,lamdasignal,PA,'plot','plot');

hold on

SP1=1560; %your point goes here
line([SP1 SP1],get(hax,'YLim'),'Color',[1 1 0],'Linewidth',4)
annotation('textarrow',[0.4,0.45],[0.2,0.2],...
           'String','\lambda_p= 1560 nm ')

title({'Linear phase mismatch vs signal wavelength' ;'in anomalous dispersion regime'},'fontsize',12)    
ylabel(ax(1),'Phase mismatch(/km))','fontsize',12) % label left y-axis
ylabel(ax(2),'Phase mismatch(\gamma P))','fontsize',12) % label right y-axis
xlabel(ax(2),'Signal wavelength(nm)','fontsize',12) % label x-axis


fill([lamdasignal fliplr(lamdasignal)],[deltabeta f2],'r')

hold off
```

Comment: Sorry, can you extend the explanation of what you want? You want the middle area (where the yellow line and the \lambda is) in red and not the rest?

Comment: Yes i want red region below the main curve called delta beta 
where deltabeta is covered by a window starting from -4 gamma P to 0

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time since you asked this but the following line is what you are after. 
patch is a polygon creation function in this simple example you take a closed X vector and a corresponding closed Y vector. 
You just need to take care to both close the polygon and take it to the floor of the graph to avoid weird looking polygon's hence the min/max(xlim).
enjoy.

```
patch(([lamdasignal max(xlim) min(xlim)]),([min(deltabeta, -4.*N) min(ylim) min(ylim)]),[0 0 1]);
```